# PyQt5 can't add a label to scroll area from thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, pyqt, pyqt5

I use a thread to receive messages from the socket server. I receive the message and try and add a label and I get the next error: "QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread"

Can someone please explain to me why it doesn't work and what should I do in order to make this work?

```
def threaded_receiveMessage(chat, network):
    while True:
        try: 
            chatterMessage = network.recieveData()
            if chatterMessage:
                chat.addLabel(chatterMessage, selfThread = chat)
        except:
            print("Disconnected.")
            break



class RandomChattingMW(object):
    def RandomChattingSetup(self, MainWindow, username):
        # Connecting to network.
        self.username = username
        self.network = Network(username)
        start_new_thread(threaded_receiveMessage, (self, self.network))

    def addLabel(self, text):
            print("Adding a label")
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(text)
            label.setStyleSheet("font: 11pt;")
            label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
            print(selfThread)
            self.lineEdit.setText("")
            self.layout.addWidget(label)
```

This is just part of the code I don't think there's a need for everything. and just to make sure I am clear, I get a string from network.recieveData() which is a function that runs socket.recv in another file, and it does call the addLabel function, it crashes at this line: "self.lineEdit.setText("")"

Full code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import math
from NetWorkFolder.network import Network
from NetWorkFolder.NetworkManager import NetworkManager
from _thread import *

class RandomChattingMW(object):
    def RandomChattingSetup(self, MainWindow, username):
        # Connecting to network.
        self.username = username
        self.network = Network(username)


        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(540, 590)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")


        self.buttons()
        self.lineEdits()
        self.randomWidgetSetup()
        self.labels()
        self.lineLength = 73

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        #NetWork Manager
        self.manager = NetworkManager(self.network)
        self.manager.messageChanged.connect(self.addLabel)




    def buttons(self):
        # Send message button
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 560, 61, 31))
        self.pushButton.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.pushButton.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButton.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('chatParts/sendPic.png'))
        self.pushButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(50,31))
        self.pushButton.setText("")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.sendMessage)
        # Change Chat Button
        self.newChatButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.newChatButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, -1, 121,32))
        self.newChatButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.newChatButton.setText("New Chat")
        self.newChatButton.setStyleSheet("font-size:11pt")
        self.newChatButton.setObjectName("newChatButton")
        self.newChatButton.clicked.connect(self.newChatConnection)


    def lineEdits(self):
        # Write message to chat.
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 560, 480, 30))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

    def labels(self):
        # My Username
        self.usernameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.usernameLabel.setEnabled(True)
        self.usernameLabel.setText("Username: " + self.username)
        self.usernameLabel.setStyleSheet("font-size:11pt")
        self.usernameLabel.move(0,0)       
        self.usernameLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|
        QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.usernameLabel.setObjectName("usernameLabel")

        self.usernameLabel.resize(self.usernameLabel.sizeHint().width(), 30)
        # The person i am chatting with.
        self.chatUsernameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.chatUsernameLabel.setEnabled(True)
        self.chatUsernameLabel.setText("Chatter: " + "Name")
        self.chatUsernameLabel.setStyleSheet("font-size:11pt")
        self.chatUsernameLabel.move(self.usernameLabel.sizeHint().
        width()+15,0)
        self.chatUsernameLabel.setAlignment(
        QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.chatUsernameLabel.setObjectName("chatUsernameLabel")
        self.chatUsernameLabel.resize(
        self.chatUsernameLabel.sizeHint().width(), 30)
    def randomWidgetSetup(self):
        # Chat. ScrollArea
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 540, 530))
        self.scrollArea.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        # Body that holds the widgets.
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        # Box that holds the widgets.
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.layout.addStretch(-1)
        self.layout.setSpacing(10)

    # Adds a label with the message sent to you/you sent to the scroll area.
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def addLabel(self, text):
            print("Adding a label")
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(text)
            label.setStyleSheet("font: 11pt;")
            label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
            print(selfThread)
            self.lineEdit.clear()
            self.layout.addWidget(label)
    # Makes the message.
    def sendMessage(self):
        pass

    # Send the message to the network.
    def sendMessageNetwork(self, message):
        try:
            self.network.send(message)
        except:
            self.addLabel("All The User's have Left the chat!\nClick on new chat to find a new Group!")


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "RandomChatting"))
```

I put the NetworkManager class in another file so it will be a bit cleaner but its the same as what you wrote.

Comment: As the error message suggests, you can't modify your interface directly from a different thread other than the application thread itself. The proper way to do what you want is to use PyQt's signals and slots, by a) connecting a slot in your thread to the `threaded_receiveMessage` method, b) emitting a signal once that thread reaches whatever condition is needed to call the connected method. [More info and examples here](https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/concurrent-execution/multithreading-pyqt-applications-qthreadpool/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand the problem you must have the following clear concepts:

- When a widget is added to the window then the widget is a child of the window.
- Widgets are not thread-safe, so they should not be accessed from another thread.
- Parent widgets access child widgets so the child must belong to the same thread as the parent.

With the above it is concluded that widgets should not be created in another thread but that is what you are doing causing the error, the solution in these cases is to send the information ("chatterMessage") to the GUI thread through a thread element -safe as the signals where widgets should be created.

Considering the above, a possible solution is the following implementation:

```py
class NetworkManager(QtCore.QObject):
    messageChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, network, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._network = network

    @property
    def network(self):
        return self._network

    def start(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self._execute, daemon=True).start()

    def _execute(self):
        while True:
            try:
                message = self.network.recieveData()
                if message:
                    self.messageChanged.emit(message)
            except:
                print("Disconnected.")
                break


class RandomChattingMW(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        # ...


class RandomChatting(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, RandomChattingMW):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def addLabel(self, text):
        print("Adding a label")
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel(text)
        label.setStyleSheet("font: 11pt;")
        label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.lineEdit.clear()
        self.layout.addWidget(label)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = RandomChatting()
    w.show()
    network = Network(username)
    manager = NetworkManager(network)
    manager.messageChanged.connect(w.addLabel)
    manager.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

<sub>Note: I have considered that RandomChattingMW has been created with Qt Designer so you must restore that code.</sub>

Comment: I have a problem implementing what you sent in my code I get: TypeError: connect() failed between NetworkManager.messageChanged[str] and addLabel()
Now I would like to show you my full code so you be able to see how I tried to implement it.
I am opening the randomChatting window from a login window after I click a button and so it doesn't have the last part you sent if __name__ ==..... 
is there a way I can send you the code without editing here cause its with the part of the code you told me to implement.

Comment: @Matan **Edit** your question and **add** the code there at **the end**.

Comment: @Matan Have you read the small letters in my answer? Don't modify the class generated by Qt Designer so it runs pyuic and adds the code from my answer.

Comment: but this window is being opened from another class so I can't add the last part of your code which is from if __name__ == "__main__" because I am calling the RandomChattingSetup from another window script so it will never execute the __main__ part

Comment: @Matan So what you have provided me is not an [MRE], if you want help then provide what has been asked of you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212815/discussion-between-matan-and-eyllanesc).